# Inject code in to an iframe on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add some html and javascript code to an iframe when it loads so that, while the user surfs, it will go to other links through an iframe.

I have tried:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<body>
     <button id='button1' onclick="changecode()">Change Code</button>
     <iframe id='iframe1' name='iframe1' src='http://example.in/Default.aspx'> </iframe>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function changecode(){
             $('#iframe1').contents().find('div.xyz').load('2.html');
          }
     </script>
</body>
```

Another javascript attempt:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changecode() {
         document.frames('iframe1').document
            .getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdatePanel1').innerHTML='11';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: if the code is specific to the page that is loading in the iframe why not put that code inside `script` tags in the file being loaded in the iframe.

Comment: @DanyKhalife The iframe's code may not be available to the OP.  This could be for a GreaseMonkey script or having an iframe of an external page that OP want to add more functionality to.

Comment: @DavidStarkey ah yes of course, good point

Answer (score 1):

The load event will not fire from an html element of a document, but you can attach a load handler from the frame itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changecode(){
        $('#iframe1').load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find('div.xyz').html('11');
        });
    }

</script>
```